# how to sort documents using the erlang map reduce in riak

Tags: erlang, mapreduce, riak

i'm using riak to store json documents right now, and i want to sort them based on some attribute, let's say there's a key, i.e

{
     "someAttribute": "whatever",
     "order": 1
 }

so i want to sort the documents based on the "order".

I am currently retrieving the documents in riak with the erlang interface.  i can retrieve the document back as a string, but i dont' really know what to do after that. i'm thinking the map function just reduces the json document itself, and in the reduce function, i'd make a check to see whether the item i'm looking at has a higher "order" than the head of the rest of the list, and if so append to beginning, and then return a lists:reverse.

despite my ideas above i've had zero results after almost an entire day, i'm so confused with the erlang interface in riak.  can someone provide insight on how to write this map/reduce function, or just how to parse the json document?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, You do not have access to Input list in Map. You emit from Map a document as 1 element list.

Inputs (all the docs to handle as {Bucket, Key}) -> Map (handle single doc) -> Reduce (whole list emitted from Map).

Maps are executed per each doc on many nodes whereas Reduce is done once on so called coordinator node (the one where query was called).

Solution:

1. Define Inputs (as a list or bucket)
2. Retrieve Value in Map and emit whole doc or {Id, Val_to_sort_by)
3. Sort in Reduce (using regular list:keysort)

Comment: i'm sort of confused, in the riak / java script examples they can do this.

function(value, keyData, arg) {
  var data = Riak.mapValuesJson(value)[0];
  if(data.High && data.High > 600.00)
    return [value.key];
  else
    return [];
}

so they get whatever they're looking at in the var data.
then they do a data.High as if it was an attribute. i guess it depends on
how they even put in the document in the first place.  can't i do the same for the order?  (isn't that the "input" part you're talking about)

Comment: In the example given, the statement is used to filter out data in the map phase. Sorting can not be done in a map phase as it operates on a single record at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a map reduce solution but you should check out [Riak Search](http://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK/Riak+Search).

Comment: can you explain how riak search would help me out?  it looks like its' just a more efficient mechanism to tag items so i can retrieve them later.  their erlang API example is

search:search(<<"books">>, <<"author:joyce">>).

so i can find search the bucket books, for the say a json document with a key "author" and a value of "joyce".  my problem is i need to sort by a particular atttribute.  how would riak search do it?

Answer (score 1):

so i "solved" the problem using javascript, still can't do it using erlang. 
here is my query

```
{"inputs":"test",
 "query":[{"map":{"language":"javascript",
                  "source":"function(value, keyData, arg){ var data = Riak.mapValuesJson(value)[0]; var obj = {}; obj[data.order] = data; return [ obj ];}"}},
         {"reduce":{"language":"javascript",
                    "source":"function(values, arg){ return [ values.reduce(function(acc, item){ for(var order in item){ acc[order] = item[order]; } return acc;  }) ];}",
                    "keep":true}}
         ]
}
```

so in the map phase, all i do is create a new array, obj, with the key as the order, and the value as the data itself.  so visually, the obj is like this

```
{"1":{"firstName":"John","order":1}
```

in the reduce phase, i'm just putting it in the accumulator, so basically that's the sort if you think about it, because when you're done, everything will be put in order for you.  so i put 2 json documents for testing, one is above, the ohter is just firstName: Billie, order 2. and here is my result for the query above

```
[{"1":{"firstName":"John","order":1},"2":{"firstName":"Billie","order":2}}]
```

so it works! .  but i still need to do this in ERLANG, any insights?

Comment: what you're doing is returning from Maps parts of self sorted structure - but only from JS VM point of view. In Erlang, I do not see equivalent (you need to have whole structure and add elements to it to keep it sorted). Maybe spawn a process and save a value in sorted ETS set?

Comment: (Spawn needed to avoid deadlocks on vnodes)

Comment: more details: before invoking M/R create pubic sorted ETS table. Pass name/id to Maps. In each map save value to the table. In reduce, just retrieve data. Or even skip reduce - you can use table id to get data later. From Erlang point of view, this is not the best solution because it presents global state (ETS), however it may be handy.